# Multi device RSA encryption for iOS, Android and Web

Tags: javascript, android, swift, encryption, rsa

I am working on a messenger app which provides end to end RSA encryption. The messenger is developed for iOS (Swift), Android and Web (JavaScript). For 1 month I can’t get forward because I haven’t found any solution for RSA multi platform encryption. I found for any platform a solution but I cant decrypt my messages on iOS which I encrypted on Android…

I am using:

- **Swift**: Swift-RSAUtils ( https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils )
- **Android**: java.security
- **JavaScript**: JSEncrypt ( https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt )

I have a few questions which I can’t answer myself because I am not so experienced in security.

1. Is it possible to make native rss encryption on multiple devices with Android (Java), iOS (Swift) and Web (JavaScript)?
2. Is RSA the best method to make a „secure“ messenger? My „system“ looks like this:

User A Signs UP (Making a public and a private key in the application…  -> Encrypt the private  -> key with AES and store both keys in the DB)  -> User A writes a message to User B -> The message is send to User B encrypted with his public key and to User A encrypted with his public key (so both can read the messages) -> User B decrypts the encrypted message with his private Key

Or is there a better method which improves security and performance?

3. Do you have any advice what I could use for Swift, Android and JS?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It's a start. You'd need a lot more. 3. Questions for off-site resources are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you are using Javascript already in one of your apps, use it on all platforms and put your app in a Cordova wrapper.

Comment: @GeroldMeisinger I try to do it with native apps for android and iOS, because of the performance problems with hybride Apps.

Answer (score 0):

1. It has to work but I don't know how. Especially for swift it is hard to find something. I am pretty sure Android supports PKC8 Key too. Your Swift solutions doesn't support any other Key format. ( https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils/issues/2 )

2.Take a look here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35471/is-there-any-particular-reason-to-use-diffie-hellman-over-rsa-for-key-exchange 
Diffie-Hellman is probably the better solution.

3. Even if it is a bit off topic I am interested how to make encryption with Android and Swift compatible. I think you should search for a DH solution...